# How to replace an image texture with another one using python API?

Tags: python

As shown in the screenshot below,
There is a cube labeled 1,
and I copied it with ctrl+c and ctrl+v,
and then I got Cube 2.

[image]

**Question:**
The question is on cube 2.
I need to replace the image texture "001.png.001" with another image "002.png" using **Python API**,
I've already prepared that image,the path is "F:\blender_projects\images\002.png",
how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bpy

material = bpy.context.object.material_slots['Material'].material
image_texture_node = material.node_tree.nodes['Principled BSDF'].inputs['Base Color'].links[0].from_node
image_texture_node.image = bpy.data.images.load(filepath='F:\blender_projects\images\002.png', check_existing=True)
```